# How-to Ubuntu 11.04 +Java Swing/SWT menu in header(like in Mac OS)?

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu, swt

Is there a way to put a menu on a panel in Java's Swing/SWT applications in Ubuntu 11.04 (like in Mac OS X)? I've seen that most (if not all) of native applications on Ubuntu use this feature. So, is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while to understand what you meant. If you mean you want to use the Unity desktop Global Menu, you will likely have to use the [Java Gnome Bindings](http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/)