# Non-librarian Java integration with Ubuntu's Unity

Tags: java, integration, menubar, jmenubar, ubuntu-unity

I want my Java app to integrate with the Unity UI in Ubuntu 11+, but I only want to distribute a single JAR and would prefer it to only have my code (it'll likely be in my portfolio). **Is there any way I can put the contents of a `JMenuBar` into the Unity menu bar?** I saw that there was already [a solution on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865552/how-to-ubuntu-11-04-java-swing-swt-menu-in-headerlike-in-mac-os), and I already do this for OS X with a `System.setPropety` call, but I want to be able to do this in Ubuntu with my own code, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Technicaly this s possible, either by "one-jar" lib on source, or by using proguard obsuscation. But both technics may violate the license conditions of the libs you want to include.
For Proguard: use -injars to integrate jars into your one jar.
Link to Proguard homepage: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/

Further info see homepage of proguard.
The other technic is often called "jar in jar".

Comment: that's still not code... I want to do this literally **without** using libraries, that includes libraries compiled into my JAR

Comment: This has nothing to do with code! This is build skript!  read the proguard docu.

Comment: Scripts are still code, and your answer tells me nothing of how to script it. You're not even providing any links! There are MANY products and services called Proguard, and as far as I can tell, none of them show me what code I can use to add menus to Unity with Java.

Comment: You write your normal code as ever. Then in your build system you have to integrate an additional obfuscation step. In that step you use Proguard; or you can call Proguard from command line, too. Link is http://proguard.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Look, I don't want to integrate someone else's library. At all. In any way. I don't want to use Proguard to obfuscate it. I want to know how to do it myself, so I can learn! That's what this site is for; learning how to code better!